# Clustering similar lines with HDBSCAN

Tags: python, opencv, line-segment, hdbscan

[image]
The image above is a frame from a video. The ultimate goal is to detect the gate. What I want to do is cluster lines similarly to the circles, where the lines that are not circled are outliers. My findings tells me this is a HDBSCAN problem so I have attempted to implement HDBSCAN like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import hdbscan

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Create default Fast Line Detector (FSD)
fld = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector(_length_threshold=60,
                                          _canny_th1=5,
                                          _canny_th2=5,
                                          _canny_aperture_size=3,
                                          _do_merge=True
                                          )

# Detect lines in the image
lines = fld.detect(gray_img)

cluster_lines = []
if type(lines) is not type(None):
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        cluster_lines.append([(x1 + x2) // 2, (y1 + y2) // 2])
        # cluster_lines.append([x1, y1, x2, y2])

line_clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=3,
                                 cluster_selection_epsilon=0.5)
line_clusterer.fit(cluster_lines)
labels = line_clusterer.labels_
cluster_max = line_clusterer.labels_.max()
```

I have tried 2 approaches, one is to just pass in a list of the lines as they are, which gave really bad results and Im assuming that is because the HDBSCAN doesnt know the coordinates represent a line. The second is to pass in a list of the midpoint of every line, which works better but still not great. Is there a way that I can improve this and get something more similar to the desired result?

Original Image
[image]

Comment: I would like to try and help but there are 3 problems. 1) The only image you share is covered with annotations so I can't try to process it. 2) Your code is incomplete and you have removed `import` statements for some reason so I cannot run it. 3) I have no idea where the *"gate"* is in your image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry about that. I added imports, and the original image and added the code I use to detect the lines. Note that to install hdcscan you need numpy version 1.20.0. However, I am open to other suggestions, the goal is to detect the gate using lines since I have already tried color filtering and trying to avoid CNN's. Also keep in mind that this is rather close, we wanna be able to detect it further away as well and in murkier water i.e. conditions can vary